# I cannot find a TapKey lock's binding code

Tags: tapkey

I want to bind a tapkey lock using a binding code but then I cannot find the code, where can I find the binding code from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binding code is only provided with special agreement and typically when integrator uses many locks.
In any other cases you should use the Owner Card for binding the locks.

Nevertheless, if you have an use case and would like to discuss the agreement, contact us directly by contact form on our website.